Angular material radio button issue
I'm novice in Angular; I'm building a signup form with an "angular material radio button"  about the gender (two values only), and an "angular material data picker" about the birth date,  but the console log doesn't intercept the value choosen (gender and birthdate)
signup.component.html
`
<mat-toolbar>
  <span>Registration</span>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-card-content>
  <form #signupform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(signupform)">
    <mat-card class="my-card">
      <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field appearence="fill">
          <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            placeholder="First name"
            name="firstname"
            ngModel
          />
        </mat-form-field>

        &nbsp;
        <mat-form-field appearence="fill">
          <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            name="lastname"
            ngModel
          />
        </mat-form-field>

        &nbsp;
        <mat-form-field appearence="fill">
          <mat-label>email</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="email" name="email" ngModel />
        </mat-form-field>

        &nbsp;

        <mat-form-field appearence="fill">
          <mat-label>Phone number</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="text" name="phone" ngModel />
        </mat-form-field>

        &nbsp;
        <mat-form-field appearence="fill">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            name="password"
            ngModel
          />
        </mat-form-field>

        &nbsp;
        <mat-form-field appearence="fill">
          <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
          <mat-select name="country" ngModel>
            <mat-option value="Italy">Italy</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="France">France</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Spain">Spain</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="Germany">Germany</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>

        &nbsp;

        <mat-form-field appearence="fill">
          <mat-label>Birthdate</mat-label>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
          <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
          <mat-datepicker-toggle
            matIconSuffix
            [for]="picker"
          ></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>


        &nbsp;

        <mat-radio-group aria-label="Gender">
          <mat-radio-button value="true">Male</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="false">Female</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
      </mat-card-content>
      
      <!-- REGISTER BUTTON -->
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">INVIA</button>
      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
  </form>
</mat-card-content>

signup.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { InternalService } from './../../services/internal.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent {
 
  users:any

  form: NgForm

  constructor(){}

  ngOnInit(): void{
  }
  
  onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form)
  }
}

All angular material modules were imported in app.module.ts
What went wrong?

All the other fields have ngModel attributes, and the ones that are not working don't.

I think it's better to use reactive forms instead of template-driven forms. It will help you a lot in the future.
